# How to get email address along with people list in google plus API

Tags: php, email, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I'm using google plus API in my web app. I could pull out all people from google plus

My code is

```
$this->client = new Google_Client();
        $this->client->setApplicationName($CI->config->item('application_name', 'googleplus'));
        $this->client->setClientId($CI->config->item('client_id', 'googleplus'));
        $this->client->setClientSecret($CI->config->item('client_secret', 'googleplus'));
        $this->client->setRedirectUri($CI->config->item('redirect_uri', 'googleplus'));
        $this->client->setDeveloperKey($CI->config->item('api_key', 'googleplus'));

        $this->plus = new Google_PlusService($this->client);
              $this->auth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($this->client);

$peoples = $this->plus->people->listPeople('me','visible');
```

Here I'm getting list of all the peoples in my circle. But I dont get people's email address and birthdays. How can I get those too?

Answer (score 3):

Once you have a list of Google+ IDs, you will need to make a people.get call to gain the [public] profile data for those users. In PHP, this call looks like `$me = $plus->people->get('me');`. For an authorized user, the 'me' keyword can be used. Otherwise, you can make the call using a Google+ ID.

Once you have made that call, you can pull out the attributes that are relevant to you (full list: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people).

However, to get the Google email address for a user, you will need to include the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` scope in addition to the `plus.login` scope. This means that you may only get the email addresses of authorized users.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you have tried? I can't really help you unless I know more about what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the document on [Google+ OAuth 2.0 scopes](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth) which explains that you need to use the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` and then send your access token to the tokenInfo endpoint to get the user's email address as a part of the validation information

Comment: How can I create the request?