# Google+ api: Get users alternate email addresses

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-plus

I have added 'Sign in with Google+' to a website, using javascript.

Using the following code

```
gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
  var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
       'userId': 'me'
     });
     request.execute(function(resp) {
       console.log(resp);
     });
```

My HTML is this

```
<div id="gSignInWrapper"><div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn"> 
<span class="icon"></span> <span class="buttonText"><strong>Login</strong> with Google+</span>
</div>
</div>
```

I have this at the bottom of my page:

```
var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
       //po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
       po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=render';
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
     })();

function render() {
    gapi.signin.render('customBtn', {
      'callback': 'signinCallback',
      'clientid': '410303772734-t1k0lsm5f83lvrpbglgdbu71kj8gqsdv.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
      'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schema.org/AddAction',
      'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read'
    });`
```

This all creates the button and I can login ok.

The login response includes
`..."emails":[{"value":"mine@gmail.com","type":"account"}], ...`

The data return from Google includes an array called Emails. The array contains only the Primary email address associated with my account. How do i get all the other emails associated with the account? There are definitely other emails, I have added them today myself.

I have checked the following, but none seem to have the answer:

- [Pulling out user details from Google Plus by email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942813/pulling-out-user-details-from-google-plus-by-email-address)
- [Google OAuth API to get user's email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442668/google-oauth-api-to-get-users-email-address)
- [How to get email address along with people list in google plus API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672709/how-to-get-email-address-along-with-people-list-in-google-plus-api)
- https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth

Answer (score 0):

The emails must be public for the user in order to appear in the API response. However, the API does not seem to be returning the email list.

The following [test demo](http://wheresgus.com/emaildemo/) should work but I'm seeing the same as you. I'll follow up.